# UK Visitor visa validity after Type D Visa was issued

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, legal, tourist-visas

I am an Indian national and am traveling to the UK soon. I was issued a multi visit Type C tourist visa in 2021 with validity from 25/10/2021 - 25/10/2026.
However, in 2022 I was issued a Type D - Temporary work visa for 5 months from 20/06/2022 - 25/11/2022. I read online that after a second visa is issued, the first one can get cancelled (https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/extant-leave-ecb22/extant-leave-ecb22). However, I wasn't notified about it and my visa stamp in the passport does not have a "Cancelled Without Prejudice" sticker on it either.
I called UKVI and they verbally notified that it could have been cancelled but couldn't confirm it. I also called the Border control at the Heathrow airport and they said that my tourist visa will be valid.

I am now confused about these conflicting pieces of advice, and am wondering if there is a way for me to confirm the validity of my visa or talk to someone who can provide some concrete confirmation.
I have to travel in 10 days so any help would be appreciated! Thanks!